# How to move JSON objects into groups of [X]

Tags: javascript, json

I have a group of JSON objects and I'm trying to group them into groups of X. It looks something like this:

```
{
"1": {
     "id": "XXXXXXX",
     "author": "1001",
     },
"2": {
     "id": "XXXXXXX",
     "author": "1001",
     },
"3": {
     "id": "XXXXXXX",
     "author": "1001",
     },
"4": {
     "id": "XXXXXXX",
     "author": "998",
     }
}
```

(The IDs are all different values)
Let's say I want to grab if the author value is 1001, which I already did:

```js
var userid = "1001";
for(var v in modfile) { //modfile is the JSON object above
    if(modfile instanceof Object) {
        if(modfile[v].author !== userid) { continue; } 
}} continue;
```

Now here's what I need to know what I can't do. I want to grab those objects, e.g. object 1, 2, and 3 then move it into groups of X. E.g.

```
{
"group1":{
"1":{
"id":"XXXXXX",
"author":"1001"
},
"2":{
"id":"XXXXXX",
"author":"1001"
}
}
"group2":{
"3":{
"id":"XXXXXX",
"author":"1001"
}
}
```

Let's say groups of 2. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you explain more in depth about the modified object you want to create?

Comment: Let's say I want 2 filtered objects per group, therefore 2 groups since there are 3 objects (filtered), so there's group 1, containing object 1 & 2. group 2 has object 3. The numbered objects (which I updated) should have the id & author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good exercise, but in practice you should try to use arrays over numbered objects whenever possible. It's much more efficient.

In any case, below is an implementation that satisfies your requirements with variable group size, defaulting to two per group if given no second argument.

It creates a new object, using two counters to track the group being build and the number of items in the current group. It pushes into the current group namespace of the new object until the number of items in the group is equal to the groupSize. Then it'll create a new group namespace, increment the group counter, and reset the group items counter to zero.

```
const groupJsonParser = (json, groupSize=2) => {
  let counter = 0, // tracks new new property in the object
    groups = 0,  // tracks the groups created
    groupKey = `group${++groups}` // key to use for the group
  // iteration through the object is required. Easiest 
  // way to do this is to get the keys as an array and 
  // iterate through them. Here I'll directly synthesize the new
  // object using the reduce array method: 
  return Object.keys(json).reduce((final, key) => {
    // check if the number pushed into the current group 
    // exceeds the group limit: 
    if(counter === groupSize) {
      // if it does, reset the counter to 0
      counter = 0
      // and update the group key for the new group
      groupKey = `group${++groups}`
      // create the object for the new group and assign to
      // the new object with the group key: 
      final[groupKey] = {}
    }
    // in the current group at the current counter, set
    // the current value from the original json
    // and increment the counter: 
    final[groupKey][++counter] = json[key]

    // always return the updated object at the bottom 
    // of every iteration of reduce:
    return final
  }, {[groupKey]: {}}) /*<-- initialization value*/
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var group = {};
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(k) { // i.e. for "1", "2", "3"...
    groups[a[k].author] = groups[a[k].author] || {}; // create an empty object with key as author id
    groups[a[k].author][k] = a[k]; // add the object to the group
});
```

This will group objects by author IDs like this:

```
{
    "998": {
        "4": {
            "id": "XXXXXXX",
            "author": "998"
        }
    },
    "1001": {
        "1": {
            "id": "XXXXXXX",
            "author": "1001"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "XXXXXXX",
            "author": "1001"
        },
        "3": {
            "id": "XXXXXXX",
            "author": "1001"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it could be optimized further.